# Ionic 4 Native HTTP get data in json format

Tags: ionic4

I am getting data from api But its showing in text format how can i show it in json format.

I try it with `{"Content-Type": "application/json"}` But is also not working

```
 this.http.get('https://www.anything.co.il/api/get_posts/', {}, {"Content-Type": "application/json"})
  .then(data => {

    this.data = data.data;
    console.log(this.data);
    console.log(data.status);
    console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);

  })
  .catch(error => {

    console.log(error.status);
    console.log(error.error); // error message as string
    console.log(error.headers);

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import HttpClient in your component.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Next you need to inject HttpClient via the component's constructor

```
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient){}
```

Next, add a method where you can call HttpClient.get(ENDPOINT_URL):

No need to pass response type bydeafult angular takes response type as json

```
get_products(){ 

   this. httpClient.get('https://www.anything.co.il/api/get_posts/').subscribe(
        (res)=>{
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
```

Comment: i cant use httpclient because its giving error of access control allow origin

Comment: It should be fixed from Server side , node backend you can do something like this  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

Comment: im using to make plugin to fetch data from website. It can not possible native HTTP? its showing in text format just need to show in json

Comment: you can parse the text using JSON.parse(response),

Comment: when im console JSON.parse(response); its showing in json format but when im using like this this.data = JSON.parse(response) to use for html. So app is not w orking :(